# Find the equation of desired tangent

Tags: calculus

Find the equation of the tangent to the curve $y=2x^2$ equation at the point $(3,18)$.

Comment: Made any progress on the problem?

Comment: no i havent  im struggling

Comment: Do you know what a derivative is, and what it means?

Comment: @asleylewis Do you know derivatives?

Comment: no im kind of confused

Comment: this is what i have y-18=2(3)^2

Comment: If you know derivatives it's easy to get the equation : $$y-18=12(x-3)$$ and in general if you have the function $f$ and the point $(a,f(a))$ the equation is given by : $$y-f(a)=f'(a)(x-a)$$

Comment: weeeelll, you probably want to know what they are in order to answer this question. If you have a calculus textbook, I suggest you read the section on derivatives.

Comment: Where did this question come from? Are you studying calculus?

Answer (score 2):

If you know derivatives the simpler answer is that of Subhadeep Dey.

If you don't know derivative you can find an answer serching the straight line passing thorough the point $(3,18)$ and that has only one common point with the parabola $y=2x^2$.
The lines passing thorough the point $(3,18)$ have equation $y-18=m(x-3)$, so the problem reduced to search for which value of $m$ the system
$$
\begin{cases}
y=2x^2\\
y-18=m(x-3)
\end{cases}
$$
has only one solution, and this is done when the discriminant of the equation:
$$
m(x-3)+18=2x^2
$$
is null:
$$
\Delta=m^2-8(3m-18)=(m-12)^2=0
$$
so we find $m=12$ and the equation of the tangent is $y-18=12(x-3)$

Comment: yeah, neat answer

Answer (score 0):

here $y'=4x$.

Hence, $y'_{(3,18)}=12$

So the slope of your tangent at $(3,18)$ is $12$

So, the equation is $$y-18=12(x-3)\\\Rightarrow 12x-y=18$$